# Cannot display PHP $_POST variables in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display a number in a bootstrap modal after i use post method to submit a form .

But the bootstrap modal cannot show out the number ($_POST[number]).

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
<label class="control-label" >Number</label>
<div class="controls">
    <input class="form-control" name="number" type="text">

    <p class="help-block">Enter a number</p>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">submit</button>
<?php
$number = $_POST['number'];
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close"
                        data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                    &times;
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                    number
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <?php
                echo $number;
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                        data-dismiss="modal">close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                    ok
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Have you actually posted anything or submitted a form?

Comment: Is there any error message?

Comment: I can display the bootstrap modal but the number can not show out .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few observations and flaws with your approach:

- Fix HTML Errors (e.g. you are not properly closing your form, add: `</form>`
- PHP is a server-side scripting language.
- Bootstrap cannot function without Jquery which is a client-side scripting language.
- You cannot trigger a Bootstrap modal on a form submission button, unless its Ajax driven!
- Show the Modal after the form has been submitted (Page load) [see jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/shillie/3bz219sg/1/)

Complete code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
      <label class="control-label" >Number</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" name="number" type="text">        
        <p class="help-block">Enter a number</p>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">submit</button>
    </form>  
    <?php if (isset($_POST["number"])) : ?>
    <!-- Show the Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close"
            data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
              &times;
            </button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
              number
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
              echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["number"]);
            ?>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            data-dismiss="modal">close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
              ok
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>  
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function(){
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });
</script>
<?php else : ?>
<!-- Do other stuff here -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: if i want to send the number to database after i click ok in Bootstrap modal, the PHP code need to add in where?

Comment: Quick answer: It goes before the Bootstrap modal (See example here [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp))

        <?php if (isset($_POST["number"])) : ?>
          <?php
            $number = $_POST["number"];
            $sql = "INSERT INTO YOURTABLE (number)
            VALUES ($number)";
          ?>
        <!-- Show the Modal -->

Comment: i mean the number will insert to database after i click "ok" button in bootstrap modal window , i not expect the database will insert after i click submit .
Can i add php code in <?php else : ?> <?php{php cade (insert to database} ?> <?php endif; ?>   ?

Comment: Hi @paul0080 you will have to use Ajax for this, post the value using jQuery post() example: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_post.asp)

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you didn't close your `form` tag and you are trying to use `submit` button as a button for your `modal`...I don't know if that is gonna work.

Close your `form` tag and add `input` field of `submit` type...and then add a `button` for modal..that will work.

Here is the working code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../includes/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
    <label class="control-label" >Number</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="form-control" name="number" type="text">

        <p class="help-block">Enter a number</p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    ?>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type="submit">Modal</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        &times;
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                        number
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <?php
                    echo $number;
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                            data-dismiss="modal">close
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                        ok
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../includes/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Change `<script>` and `<link>` tag source according to your needs.

Comment: sorry , it should have a </form> in the back.

Comment: I can display the bootstrap modal but the number that i input can not show out .

Comment: i want to click submit button and that the bootstrap modal will show out the number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add one more button ( input submit button ). that button will send the post request to self and update the variable $number.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

u can remove class model and fade from 'myModel' class div or can write style for display:block. I tried your code and checked in my browser and removed above classes. I hope you get the problem. You can also view your number with viewing page source.

Comment: remove class model in where?

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed something about this Modal Problem,  remove   `type="button"` from your `<button>` and the code runs.

Answer (score -1):

Would have posted this as comment but I don't have enough rep yet.

This is because the PHP code gets executed server side and is executed before the HTML is loaded, so the `$number` is an empty string.

Comment: so how can i show the number in bootstrap modal by using php?